# How to trigger or call jquery load function multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help. I'm struggling with some problem for a while. I need to call jquery load function every time i click on a button. To trigger load function I suppose I need to refresh that particular div or load that div again.

My goal is:

when I click on the button I want loading-div to be shown and I want .image-container to load again. I suppose that should trigger jquery load function that will hide loading-div when .image-container loads.

This is my code:

```
$(".image-container").load(function(){
   $( "#loading-div" ).hide();
});

$("#button").on('click', function(){
   $( "#loading-div" ).show();
   $(".image-container").load("index.php"); // load again div that sholud trigger upper function
});
```

Comment: since it was already loaded ..  It may need a callback??

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    $( "#loading-div" ).show();
    $(".image-container").load("index.php", function () {
        $( "#loading-div" ).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: it only shows div but it doesnt hide it. I have put alert above hide function and it doesnt call it

Answer (score 0):

suppose I want to Load data from the server to the particular div tag continuously.
forthat i use setinterval jquery method.
example:

```
setinterval(function(){
$("div1").load("url","data you want to send to your  server");                      
                      },1000);
```

note: load method work only for 'get' method.in above code second parameter of load is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, just separate desired pre/post-load logic from handlers?

```
function loadSome(el, data) {
   $("#loading-div").show();
   el.load(data, function () {
     $("#loading-div").hide();
   });
}

function loadImage() {
    loadSome($(".image-container"), "index.php");
}

loadImage();
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    loadImage();
});
```

Or in more `jQuery`-way:

```
jQuery.fn.progressedLoad = function (data, progressElement) {
    $(progressElement).show();
    // add more complex load-progress logic here...

    return this.load(data, function() {
        $(progressElement).hide();
    });
}

...

$(".image-container").progressedLoad(
    {"url": "index.php"}, 
    $("#loading-div")
);
```

Comment: i get the same result as in above answer, it only shows but it doesn hide loading-div

Comment: 1) is desired content loaded into `.image-container`, or it just shows `#loading-div` and then do nothing? 2) which version of jQuery you using? `.load()` can have different parameters list and can behave like `.on("load", function(){})` in some usecases in jQuery versions prior to 1.9

Comment: 1) every time i click on button content of .image-container changes, but sometimes it last few seconds, so i created function that will show #loading-div until loads finish 2) jquery-2.1.3

Comment: Its odd, as it works fine for me. Well... so: 1) whats in console? any errors on load? 2) is `#loading-div` inside `.image-container` or maybe its changing in some other way, so `$("#loading-div")` reference becomes invalid? have you tried `$(".image-container").progressedLoad({"url": "index.php"}, "#loading-div");` instead? 3) is there possibly param-list difference? have you tried `$(".image-container").progressedLoad("index.php", "#loading-div");` as well? 4) have you tried to create minimal reproducible example on something like jsFiddle?